# http request in dart is not behaving the same as in postman

Tags: http, dart, postman

I am trying the write a program that uses the public API for the online investment broker Questrade.

You manually generate a refresh token on the website, and then pass it to a request to get an access token.

```
Use the token you copied to redeem it for an access token and the server or practice server URL using the following command:

https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=

or

https://practicelogin.questrade.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=
```

I structured the GET request in postman as follows, and it succeeds and receives a valid json body.

```
https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MT1men5gBhSXyv15e6j7gC4CrD8msq3P0
```

In dart I structure the request as follows...

```
static Future<AccessToken> getAccessToken(String refreshToken) async {
      var uri = Uri.https("login.questrade.com", "/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$refreshToken");
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      print(response);
      var json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return AccessToken.fromJson(json);
    }
```

But all it give me is an actually html response that looks like it is a login page(too big to post).

So it seems like the endpoint is treating these requests differently, but I can not figure out what is different about these two requests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `Uri` wrong since you are using the path as a way to encode data which does not work since it will try encode `&`. You can see the problem if you print your `uri` object:

```
https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token%3Fgrant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MT1men5gBhSXyv15e6j7gC4CrD8msq3P0
```

Instead, do something like this where you provide the data to the `Uri.https` constructor:

```
void main() {
  var refreshToken = 'MT1men5gBhSXyv15e6j7gC4CrD8msq3P0';
  var uri = Uri.https(
    'login.questrade.com',
    '/oauth2/token',
    <String, String>{
      'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
      'refresh_token': refreshToken,
    },
  );
  print(uri);
  // https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MT1men5gBhSXyv15e6j7gC4CrD8msq3P0
}
```

Comment: This just gives me 'bad request'. Postman still succeeds reliably.

Comment: @Scorb You are not providing much details about how you are calling the API though Postman (e.g. if you have any headers being set). But start by checking that the generated URI in Dart is the same as the one being generated in Postman. If you are complete lost, please upload some screenshots of your Postman configuration so we can verify that your Dart code is doing the same as Postman.

Comment: I just did not implement this solution correctly. My bad :\